# tensorflow placeholder in function

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

Now, I have a bit of code like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])
y = x * 2

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [2, 4, 6]})
    print(result)
```

I want to feed values to a function.

Below is an obvious wrong.
How do I suppose to do that?

```
import tensorflow as tf

def place_func():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])
    y = x * 2

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [2, 4, 6]})
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to run a session inside of function just as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_func(data):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])
    y = x * 2
    return sess.run(y, feed_dict = {x: data})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = my_func([[2, 4, 6]])
    print(result)
```

You could also create a class and let x to be a field of that class.

Comment: Why the 'data' is fed into a placeholder and not used directly in the calculation of 'y'? Can't we just say y = data * 2 ? I've noticed using placeholders for the input data of tensorflow functions. But I don't know what is the reason behind it.